# Configuring IIS 7 to run on 32 bit

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7, 32bit-64bit, wkhtmltopdf

I understand that the server can't run 32 bit and 64 bit apps concurrently, but I need to make use of the [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) utility which is only available as a 32 bit binary. If I "downgrade" my environment to 32 bit (ASP.NET app, IIS), what affect will this have on performance? Will it break anything?

Comment: I don't understand how shelling out to run a 32 bits (command line) utility would force you to downgrade your *entire* server to 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

".. the server can't run 32 bit and 64 bit apps concurrently"

You can have an application pool running in 32 and another in 64 bits in the same IIS instance.

https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx

Create a dedicated application pool to run this application, leave all other apps in 64 bits mode

Comment: Seems promising but isn't IIS a web server? Are you suggesting I create an empty web app where this utility will reside, set the application pool to 32 bit, and call the utility by its directory in the file system?

Comment: It seems to be working even without setting the app pool to 32-bit. Flummoxed, but anyway.

Comment: I'm suggesting to create different application pools for each different configuration needed.